# Fractions work individually but not in table

Tags: tables, equations, fractions

I am trying to create a table with some equations inside but with no success. I use the following code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ m{8em} | m{7cm}}
        \hline
        Index & Formula \\
        \hline
        Burn Area Index (BAI) &\[\frac{1}{(0.1 - Red)\textsuperscript{2} + (0.06 - NIR)\textsuperscript{2}}\]\\ 
        Difference Vegetation Index (dvi)&NIR - Red\\
        Enhanced Vegetation Index (EVI)&2.5\times\[\frac{NIR - Red}{(NIR + 6\times Red - 7.5\times Blue + 1)}\]\\  
        Normalised Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI)&\textrm{NDVI}=\[\frac{NIR - Red}{(NIR + Red}\]\\
        Leaf Area Index (LAI)&3.618\times EVI - 0.118\\
        Normalised Burn Ration (NBR)&\[\frac{(NIR - SWIR)}{(NIR + SWIR)}\]\\
        Difference Normalised Burn Ration (DNBR)& (Pre-fire NBR) - (Post- fire NBR) \\
        Normalised Difference Water Index (NDWI)&[\frac{($\rho_857$ - $\rho_1241$)}{($\rho_857$ - $\rho_1241$)}\] \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

If I use only the fraction in the text I have no issues (e.g. `\[\frac{(NIR - SWIR)}{(NIR + SWIR)}\]`)  and I can not see the problem here.

Any ideas?

Comment: You must place math-mode macros, such as `\times`, in math mode.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for the suggestion. I did that like \[2.5\times\frac{NIR - Red}{(NIR + 6\times Red - 7.5\times Blue + 1)}\], but still I have a problem. I think that the way I add the fraction to the table causes me a problem but I can not see it.

Comment: @geo_dd: In the code fragment you posted, not all commands that can be only used in math mode are actually in math mode and the last table row contains redundant `$` signs.

Comment: @geo_dd - Please see the complete answer I posted a short while ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of applying display-style math mode to each individual formula in the second column, I would redefine the column type so that its contents are treated automatically as being math-mode material. In the code below, I use the `c` column type for the right-hand column since line breaks wouldn't seem to be a good idea.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e,booktabs}
%% Define a new column type, for centered automatic displaystyle math mode material
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} 
                    >{\RaggedRight}m{8em} 
                    C % <-- note use of "C" column type
                    @{}}
        \toprule
        Index & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Formula} \\
        \midrule
        Burn Area Index (BAI)
        & \frac{1}{(0.1-\mathrm{Red})^2 + (0.06-\mathrm{NIR})^2} \\
        \addlinespace
        Difference Vegetation Index (dvi)
        &\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{Red}\\
        \addlinespace
        Enhanced Vegetation Index (EVI)
        &2.5\times\frac{\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{Red}}{%
          (\mathrm{NIR} + 6\times \mathrm{Red}
          - 7.5\times \mathrm{Blue} + 1)}\\
        \addlinespace
        Normalised Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI)
        &\textrm{NDVI}=\frac{\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{Red}}{%
          \mathrm{NIR} + \mathrm{Red}}\\
        \addlinespace
        Leaf Area Index (LAI)
        &3.618\times \mathrm{EVI} - 0.118\\
        \addlinespace
        Normalised Burn Ration (NBR)
        &\frac{\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{SWIR}}{%
          \mathrm{NIR} + \mathrm{SWIR}}\\
        \addlinespace
        Difference Normalised Burn Ration (DNBR)
        & (\textrm{Pre-fire NBR}) - (\textrm{Post-fire NBR}) \\
        \addlinespace
        Normalised Difference Water Index (NDWI)
        &\frac{\rho_{857} - \rho_{1241}}{\rho_{857} - \rho_{1241}} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aside: If you don't want to allow hyphenation in the left-hand column, change `\RaggedRight` to `\raggedright` in the column definition.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestion to avoid individual math-modes is really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I have a question related to your example. At the tables I usually use it is easy to add extra columns but how can I do this with your example? I keep get an error about an extra alignment.

Comment: @geo_dd - I've edited the code, to first define a new column type called `C`, and later use `C` inside a `tabular` environment. Does this help you? If not, please go ahead and ask a new question, related specifically to how to add columns of some special type to a `tabular` environment.