# Add a text multicolumn to a tabular

Tags: tables, arrays, multicolumn

As a new user, I have many questions which I will ask separately now that I have finished my first text and want to improve it. Following my previous question ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435560/fractions-work-individually-but-not-in-table/435580?noredirect=1#comment1092325_435580)), I want to add to my table a third column, with the explanation of the indices but I have no success.
I think the solution is somewhere here([tabular environments](https://ctan.org/pkg/array))

Thank you for any ideas.

```
 documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array,ragged2e,booktabs}
    %% Define a new column type, for centered automatic displaystyle math mode material
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{landscape}
            \begin{tabular}{@{} 
                    >{\RaggedRight}m{8em} 
                    C % <-- note use of "C" column type
                    @{}}
                \toprule
                Index & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Formula} \\
                \midrule
                Burn Area Index (BAI)
                & \frac{1}{(0.1-\mathrm{Red})^2 + (0.06-\mathrm{NIR})^2} \\
                \addlinespace
                Difference Vegetation Index (dvi)
                &\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{Red}\\
                \addlinespace
                Enhanced Vegetation Index (EVI)
                &2.5\ast\frac{\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{Red}}{%
                    (\mathrm{NIR} + 6\ast \mathrm{Red}
                    - 7.5\ast \mathrm{Blue} + 1)}\\
                \addlinespace
                Normalised Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI)
                &\textrm{NDVI}=\frac{\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{Red}}{%
                    \mathrm{NIR} + \mathrm{Red}}\\
                \addlinespace
                Leaf Area Index (LAI)
                &3.618\ast \mathrm{EVI} - 0.118\\
                \addlinespace
                Normalised Burn Ration (NBR)
                &\frac{\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{SWIR}}{%
                    \mathrm{NIR} + \mathrm{SWIR}}\\
                \addlinespace
                Difference Normalised Burn Ration (DNBR)
                & (\textrm{Pre-fire NBR}) - (\textrm{Post-fire NBR}) \\
                \addlinespace
                Normalised Difference Water Index (NDWI)
                &\frac{\rho_{857} - \rho_{1241}}{\rho_{857} - \rho_{1241}} \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \captionof{table}{Table Title} \label{tab:title}    
        \end{landscape}
    \end{center}
```

Comment: What is your `C` column type? Could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: @Bernard, The C column, is Mico's suggestion from my previous question. Thanks for the note.

Comment: That's what I spontaneously did to make the fragment compilable :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra column for the explanation as shown in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
 \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{} 
                >{\RaggedRight}m{8em} 
                C
                m{8cm}
                @{}}
            \toprule
            Index & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Formula} & Explanation \\
            \midrule
            Burn Area Index (BAI)
            & \frac{1}{(0.1-\mathrm{Red})^2 + (0.06-\mathrm{NIR})^2} 
            & Here you can add some explanation of the indices. The explanatory text can span multiple lines and is vertically centered with respect to the same row's contents of the pervious two columns\\
            \addlinespace
            Difference Vegetation Index (dvi)
            &\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{Red}\\
            \addlinespace
            Enhanced Vegetation Index (EVI)
            &2.5\ast\frac{\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{Red}}{%
                (\mathrm{NIR} + 6\ast \mathrm{Red}
                - 7.5\ast \mathrm{Blue} + 1)}\\
            \addlinespace
            Normalised Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI)
            &\textrm{NDVI}=\frac{\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{Red}}{%
                \mathrm{NIR} + \mathrm{Red}}\\
            \addlinespace
            Leaf Area Index (LAI)
            &3.618\ast \mathrm{EVI} - 0.118\\
            \addlinespace
            Normalised Burn Ration (NBR)
            &\frac{\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{SWIR}}{%
                \mathrm{NIR} + \mathrm{SWIR}}\\
            \addlinespace
            Difference Normalised Burn Ration (DNBR)
            & (\textrm{Pre-fire NBR}) - (\textrm{Post-fire NBR}) \\
            \addlinespace
            Normalised Difference Water Index (NDWI)
            &\frac{\rho_{857} - \rho_{1241}}{\rho_{857} - \rho_{1241}} \\
            \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Table Title} \label{tab:title}    
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

If you want to automatically make the table as wide as the current linewidth, you could also use `tabularx` as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
 \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} 
                >{\RaggedRight}m{8em} 
                C
                X
                @{}}
            \toprule
            Index & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Formula} & Explanation \\
            \midrule
            Burn Area Index (BAI)
            & \frac{1}{(0.1-\mathrm{Red})^2 + (0.06-\mathrm{NIR})^2} 
            & Here you can add some explanation of the indices. The explanatory text can span multiple lines and is vertically centered with respect to the same row's contents of the pervious two columns\\
            \addlinespace
            Difference Vegetation Index (dvi)
            &\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{Red}\\
            \addlinespace
            Enhanced Vegetation Index (EVI)
            &2.5\ast\frac{\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{Red}}{%
                (\mathrm{NIR} + 6\ast \mathrm{Red}
                - 7.5\ast \mathrm{Blue} + 1)}\\
            \addlinespace
            Normalised Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI)
            &\textrm{NDVI}=\frac{\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{Red}}{%
                \mathrm{NIR} + \mathrm{Red}}\\
            \addlinespace
            Leaf Area Index (LAI)
            &3.618\ast \mathrm{EVI} - 0.118\\
            \addlinespace
            Normalised Burn Ration (NBR)
            &\frac{\mathrm{NIR} - \mathrm{SWIR}}{%
                \mathrm{NIR} + \mathrm{SWIR}}\\
            \addlinespace
            Difference Normalised Burn Ration (DNBR)
            & (\textrm{Pre-fire NBR}) - (\textrm{Post-fire NBR}) \\
            \addlinespace
            Normalised Difference Water Index (NDWI)
            &\frac{\rho_{857} - \rho_{1241}}{\rho_{857} - \rho_{1241}} \\
            \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{Table Title} \label{tab:title}    
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Please note, that I have replaced the `center` environment by the `\centering` command, as the former leads to additional white space that might be undesired.

Comment: thank you for your help. The problem I have with this solution though, is that it creates an empty landscape page, before the one with the table.

Comment: @geo_dd: I am unfortunately unable to recreate this behaviour. Even if I add text before and after the table, there is not empty page.

Comment: no worries, I will try to solve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @geo_dd - Did you notice that whereas your sample code places a `landscape` environment inside a `center` environment, @leandriis's solution (a) doesn't employ a `center` environment and, instead, (b) uses a `\centering` directive *inside* the `landscape` environment?

Comment: @Mico yes, I just tried it and I realised that with the \center I was using, I do not have an empty page. There are so many things to learn, I am totally newbie! Very good your notice! Thanks!